# EF core Multiple Virtual Properties with the same foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity

Is it possible in Entity Framework to use the same foreign key for seveal realted properties. For example:

```
// There is one table for credit cards. To destinguish between company credit cards and lets say shoppers credit cards there is tag field CustomerType. SO two different credit cards can have the smae EntityId but if CustomerType is different the navigatin property would point to either Client or Company table.
public enum CustomerType
{
   Client,
   Company
}

public class Client
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   virtual public IEnumerable<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }  
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    virtual public IEnumerable<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }  
}

public class CreditCard
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   //this points to either company or client depending on the customertype field.
   public int EntityId { get; set; }
   public CustomerType Type { get;set;}
   public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
 ......
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   // obviously this is wrong ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity =>
   {
       entity.HasMany(x => x.CreditCards)
           .WithOne(y => y.Client)
           .HasForeignKey(z => z.HolderId);
   });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
   {
      entity.HasMany(x => x.CreditCards)
          .WithOne(y => y.Company)
          .HasForeignKey(z => z.HolderId);
   });
 }
```

Or should I forget about it and put Company Credit cards and Client Credit cards in differnt tables. That woudl be straighforward.

Answer (score 1):

That model breaks normalization. From the table structure that is fine if there are separate tables for company vs. client credit cards, then the entities should declare a company vs. client credit card as well. It is confusing Table-per-Concrete inheritance in your proposed table structure with Table-per-Hierarchy which you seem to want to set up in your entities. It's generally best to let your entities mirror your data structure.

EF can handle this scenario through inheritance:

```
public abstract class CreditCard
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // card details
}

public class ClientCreditCard : CreditCard
{
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyCreditCard : CreditCard
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Company would have a collection of CompanyCreditCards, while Clients would have ClientCreditCards.

From the table perspective you could have a single CreditCard table with a discriminator for the credit card type, though it would have nullable IDs for both the Company or Client. (Table-Per-Hierarchy) to maintain FK relationships to the other entity. Having a Discriminator + "EntityId" that would point to either-or breaks the normalization. (No FK possible)